# Enable JMX thorough HADOOP Job api

Tags: hadoop, jmx

I want to connect to map and reduce tasks through JMX. How do I pass them JVM start-up flags like

```
   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010
```

..to map and reduce tasks?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the below command, it will add all the properties to the mapper/reducer task JVM.

```
-D mapreduce.map.java.opts="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9010 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" -D mapreduce.reduce.java.opts="<same as for map>"
```

Comment: but multiple map / reduce running on one host would clash for the port and those would get killed.